# Webdriver cannot find text on a page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to get Movie's description from here https://www.binged.com/streaming-premiere-dates/the-family-man-season-2-streaming-online-watch-on-amazon-prime/

I am running this in a loop and it misses the description for a few movies. I took the code out of the loop and just visited the same URL, then it can get the text.

I checked the `xpath` , the `full xpath` to see if something is different. It is not.

Added `WebDriverWait`. Made no difference

Added a scroll to bring it into view, still no difference.

It randomly gets the description for the same `xpath`. Can someone help me figure this out?

```
links = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="desktop"]//a')))
parent_window = driver.current_window_handle
for z in range(len(links)):
    driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);', links[z])
    all_windows = driver.window_handles
    child_window = [window for window in all_windows if window != parent_window][0]
    driver.switch_to.window(child_window)
    time.sleep(5)
    try:

       driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,825)", "")
       time.sleep(5)
       desc = []
       desc_e = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="bng-content"]//p')

       for des in desc_e:
          if des.text == '':
              continue
          desc.append(des.text)
       print(desc)
   except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        pass
```

Comment: Your xpath, `'//span[@class="desktop"]//a'`, is not working for me on that page. Can you indicate which element on the page you are trying to locate with that?

Comment: That is the start page https://www.binged.com/streaming-premiere-dates/?mode=streaming-soon. Here

Comment: I found a work around, it's to get the `text` of the whole `div`,  `desc_e = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="bng-content"]').text`.  Then it works

Comment: If you've found a solution, you should answer your own question. :)

Comment: You can fetch the description using requests module as the very content is static. Using selenium seems overkill here.

Comment: @SIM I am having to locate elements via `Text ` and `following-sibling`, because the sequence and info items are random. Is that possible with `BeautifulSoup`. That's the reason I went for selenium. Also, isn't this a bit slow website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works is to get the text of the whole `div` instead of by `p` elements.

```
desc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="bng-content"]').text
```